# Python/Kivy : Focus one TextInput to another TextInput using enter key

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

1. How to move focus from `name` TextInput to first column `(id:test1)` of dynamic add row using press enter key?
2. When press enter in `second` column (id:test2) of dynamic  `row` then new row add . How to focus first column of every row when add new row dynamic?

## test.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 300)

class User(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count)))


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

## test.kv

```
<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'


<TextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    padding_y: 3


<Row>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 40

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200

    TextInput:
        id:test1
        text: ' '
        width: 300
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: test2.focus = True

    TextInput:
        id:test2
        text: ' '
        width: 300
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: app.root.add_more()

<Rows>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

User:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 20, 20
            spacing: 10, 10

            Label:
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                id:name
                multiline: False
                text_size: self.size

        ScrollView:
            Rows:
                id: rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added the following:

1. Clock.schedule_once to ensure that the ids are defined and set focus on name (TextInput).
2. ObjectProperty because

> it is generally regarded as ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty.
>   This creates a direct reference, provides faster access and is more
>   explicit.

[Programming Guide » Kv language » Referencing Widgets](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html)

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock

Window.clearcolor = (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
Window.size = (500, 300)


class User(Screen):
    name = ObjectProperty(None)
    rows = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.set_name_focus, 1)

    def set_name_focus(self, *args):
        self.name.focus = True

    def on_enter_text_input(self):
        self.rows.row.test1.focus = True

    def add_more(self):
        self.rows.add_row()


class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    row_count = 0
    row = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.row = Row(button_text=str(self.row_count))
        self.add_widget(self.row)


class Test(App):

    def build(self):
        return self.root


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Test().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<Button@Button>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'


<TextInput@TextInput>:
    font_size: 15
    font_name: 'Verdana'
    padding_y: 3


<Row>:
    test1: test1
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    height: 40

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: None
        top: 200

    TextInput:
        id:test1
        focus: True
        text: ' '
        width: 300
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: test2.focus = True

    TextInput:
        id:test2
        text: ' '
        width: 300
        multiline: False
        on_text_validate: app.root.add_more()

<Rows>:
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: "vertical"

User:
    name: name
    rows: rows
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            padding: 20, 20
            spacing: 10, 10

            Label:
                text: "Name"
                text_size: self.size
                valign: 'middle'
            TextInput:
                id:name
                multiline: False
                text_size: self.size
                on_text_validate: root.on_enter_text_input()

        ScrollView:
            Rows:
                id: rows
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App Startup]
[image: Img02 - test1-TextInput @ Row 1]
[image: Img03 - test2-TextInput @ Row 1]
[image: Img04 - test1-TextInput @ Row 2]

Comment: Add this to each TextInput widget in the KV file:  

`code` write_tab: False